# C wrong variable values

Tags: c

I am practicing for my exam in C, and I have problem with this code. It's clear to me that in first printf program displays first unchanged values of x and y. But when we call DO, variable x should change value and accept values of `b` because of this `(a=b)`, and finally `b` should have value of this `b=(25)-15` and finally `b=10`. But my program displays 15, 15 instead of 15,10. Can some good soul explain me what I am doing wrong here ?

```
#define DO(a,b) b=(a+b)-(a=b)
int main (void)
{
    int x = 10;
    int y = 15;
    printf ("%d %d\n",x,y);
    DO(x,y);
    printf ("%d %d\n",x,y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this a typo?  `(a=b)`.  Did you mean `(a-b)` instead?

Comment: If that isn't a typo (and even if it *is*), [**you may want to read this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

Comment: In such case, C language doe not specify which assignment is executed first whether assignment to a or b. Your compiler have chosen other evaluation order as you supposed.

Comment: Strange exams you have that rely upon undefined behavior to produce a given result.

Comment: ... and that seemingly unnatural compiler choice you *cannot* rely on. Seriously read that linked question and answers.

Comment: may be you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800684/why-is-a-ab-b-a-a-bad-choice-for-swapping-two-integers

Answer (score 2):

`b=(a+b)-(a=b)`

You do two assignments in the same line, it's usually Undefined Behavior.

Didn't you mean

`b=(a+b)-(a-b)`

?

More information on Sequence Points and why what you wrote is UB [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points) (thanks Axel!)

Comment: I just wanted to say the same thing. So I'll add the link to a question where this is explained in detail as a comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points

Answer (score 2):

Your `DO` macro will expand to:

```
y = (x+y) - (x=y);
```

You have no guarantee as to which of those brackets will be evaluated first.

If `(x=y)` is evaluate first, it will evaluate to 15 (and set x to 15), so the whole thing will evaluate to

```
y = (15+15) - 15;
```

so y will be set to 15, and print `15, 15`

If `x+y` is evaluated first, the expression will evaluate as:

```
y = (10+15) - 15;
```

And y will equal to, so it will print `15, 10`.

The behaviour is thus undefined, as you do not have a sequence point which would ensure the order of evaluation. For more details on sequence points (on C++, but C is the same), look here: [Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

Answer (score 1):

From your description seems like you are trying to `swap` variable with `macro DO`

Use below macro to swap numbers..

```
#define DO(a,b){ a = a + b; b = a - b; a = a - b; }
```