# A problem with the most simple C operators

Tags: c, operators

Can someone explain how this operation works?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    int b, c;

    c = (a = 3) + (b = a + 2) - (a = 2);

    printf("%d %d %d", a, b, c);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is 2 5 5

Parentheses go first and start from the left.

c = 3 + (b = 3 + 2) - (a = 2)

c = 3 + 5 - 2

And the output should be 2 5 6

Comment: What did you expect to get instead and why?

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800684/

Answer (score 4):

The 3 assignments in `(a = 3) + (b = a + 2) - (a = 2)` are a problem as it is *undefined* behavior as they are *unsequenced*: may occur in any order or even at the same time creating bus conflicts.

Best to re-write this poor code.

Comment: I didn't intend to write this. Just wodering how this work. So what make this 3 assignments actually have a certain order to produce this output?

Comment: @KnFantasy There is no certain assignment order.  Knowing that, how might _you_ re-write it to clearly identify the assignment order you want?

Comment: @Monica I re-edit my guess. I don't want any order. If there's no certain order, then why this code always produce the same output on my computer. So it must follow a certain order, right?

Comment: @KnFantasy "So it must follow a certain order, right? " --> No.  "this code always produce the same output  on my computer"  is a premature conclusion.  Re-compile with a different compiler, optimization level or a different version, results may differ.   **C** does not specify any certain behavior here with this poor code.  The  point of code is to write such that it compiles and works the same today and  tomorrow and on your computer and others,  This code offers no  such promise.

Comment: @Monica OK but now in this compiler and with all these settings, is there any way to find out the exact order which can result in this output. Sorry for my meanless insistence.

Comment: @KnFantasy "to find out the exact order which can result in this output." --> Yes, look at the executable code, dis-assembly it and study it.  As C code, there is no certain solution.

Comment: @Monica By the way, is it useless to write and find out the order of  a complicated expression?

Comment: @KnFantasy Not useless to understand the order of a complicated well defined expression.  It is far less use to find out the order of a undefined sequence  expression such as this.

Answer (score 1):

C doesn’t force left-to-right evaluation of arithmetic expressions - each of `a = 3`, `b = a + 2`, and `a = 2` may be evaluated in any order (they are said to be *unsequenced* with respect to each other).  Since two of those expressions modify the value of `a`, the result of `b = a + 2` can vary based on the compiler, optimization settings, even the surrounding code - the result could be `7`, `5`, `2`, or something else completely.

The behavior of modifying `a` multiple times and using it in a value computation without an intervening sequence point is *undefined*, meaning the compiler isn’t required to handle the situation in any particular way.  It *may* give you the result you expect, but it doesn’t have to.  The result doesn’t have to be consistent from build to build, or even from run to run.

This should give the results you would expect based on a left-to-right reading of your expression.

```
a = 3;
b = a + 2;      // b = 5
c = a + b - 2;  // c = 6
a = 2;
```

Comment: Do you mean that if I write a + b + c. C could evaluate a + b first or b + c first?

Comment: @KnFantasy: Each of `a`, `b`, and `c` can be evaluated in any order.  Arithmetic `+` is left associative, so `a + b + c` is *parsed* as `(a + b) + c` - the result of `a + b` will be added to the result of `c`.  However, `a + b` doesn’t have to be evaluated before `c`.

Comment: So in previous expression, the side effects of `a = 3`, `b = a + 2`, and `a = 2` are evaluated in any order?

`a = 3` and `a = 2` certainly return the value of 3 and 2. In the output, `a` either get the value of `3` or `2`. `b` could be `7`, `5` or `4`.  and `c` could be `8`, `6` or `5`. None of these match your `7`, `5` ,`2`?

Comment: @KnFantasy: Typo on my part.  Point is, the result isn’t guaranteed to be consistent or predictable.

Comment: @KnFantasy Importantly C allows  `a = 3`, `b = a + 2`, and `a = 2` to be evaluated simultaneously or randomly sequenced or ....  This creates conflict as to what `a` has in the end as well as what `b` is.  It also may crash code due to a bus fault of writing two values to `a` at the same time.  There is no specified order, just chaos.  It is _undefined behavior_.